haproxy-ingress - tcp ingress for mysql
I'm trying to create an ingress for loadbalance my mysql deployment:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: mysql
  annotations:
    haproxy-ingress.github.io/balance-algorithm: roundrobin
    haproxy-ingress.github.io/maxconn-server: "500"
spec:
  ingressClassName: haproxy
  rules:
  - host: mysql.apps.k8s.mydomain.com
    tcp:
      port: 3306
        backend:
          service:
            name: mysql
            port:
              number: 3306


but when i try to apply this i get this:
error parsing mysql-ingress-haproxy.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 15: mapping values are not allowed in this context
Anyone has any idea what i'm doing wrong?
